# how to improve the performance of purePDF?

Tags: apache-flex, performance, api, printing, pdf-generation

I am using the Open source PurePDF library in my Flex AIR application. The problem is performance:

It takes 100% CPU usage and too long to generate a PDF.

- I have done some analysis on it and
  find that the text writing in pdf is
  expensive. That's why I need to know how I
  can improve the performance. Are
  there any fonts for which pdf
  generation is less expensive, or
  is there some setting or tip that can make this
  process somewhat better in terms of
  performance?
- secondly in case of images the **ImageElement** generation is very expensive when writing that element to PDF. Is there any way to reduce the processing?

**Meanwhile, I found a way to reduce the ImageElement generation processing by resizing the image using flex and by then passing the small image's bitmap data to the image element. It works fine, and i have reduced the time of execution to a good extent. Does anybody else have ideas about other problems?**

- is there any way to tell PDF to work in chunks or divide the work in such a way that it may take more time to complete but won't block the GUI while the PDF is being generated?

Please help -- thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to optimize the PDF generation with purePDF is to divide the working of purePDF component generation in chunks by creating the components time to time and the major issue resolved by image resizing

As images takes to time to be embed in PDF and the time taken in this processes is directly proportional to image size.

So 1st reduce the size of image and then embed in PDF (Keep in mind if sizes are reduced up to a large scale it will reduce the quality of image very much ) keep experimenting to get the optimum size to have good enough quality and speed for PDF generation.

The last thing is to avoid the transparent images as they need more processing only use transparency if must required otherwise use images with white background .

Answer (score 0):

> is there any way to tell PDF to work in chunks or divide the work in such a way that it may take more time to complete but don't make the GUI halted until PDF is generated

You could make the generation asynchronous by spawning a thread... The best way I've come up with to do so in flash is with the code:

```
import flash.utils.setTimeout;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.events.EventDispatcher;
...
    setTimeout(function():void {
        //TODO asynchronous schtuff
        dispatchEvent(new Event(Event.COMPLETE));
    }, 0);
```

Comment: as mentioned in Question that it takes the full CPU even i do this as you ask to do i can never handle the purePDF working as it do all the working internally

Comment: Even if you have purePDF doing it's work in a separate thread, the GUI is halted? Even if it is taking the full CPU, if it's doing something like writing a file, then it's thread should be halted occasionally so that your GUI thread can continue...

Comment: in flex there is no threading even an asyc process is not a spread thread flex does not also threading. at the end every thing ends up in frames of timeline as in flash cause flex is in the end flash running in flash player..

Comment: That's sorta silly that only file loading can be done asynchronously... Sorry to have wasted your time.

Comment: @jswolf19: As moon said, you're not actually spawning a thread.  What you're doing is postponing the execution of your function until the next frame, where it will run synchronously.

Comment: @Andrew, yeah I figured that out. I understand a little why javascript would use that model, but I'd think flash would benefit from actual threading.